# Не передается модель в частичное представление при вызове через ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Частичные представления подгружаются с помощью JS, в зависимости от значения combobox.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("loadPartial", "StartService", new { area = "Total" })',
    data: { partialName: partialName },
    async: false,
    success: function (viewName) {

    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

Метод в контроллере

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult loadPartial(string partialName)
{
    //ищем путь к представлению и передаем его
    return PartialView(path);
}
```

Главное представление и частичное - строго типизированные, модели идентичны. При этом в частичном модель не доступна (null reference exception)

При вызове с помощью `@Html.Partial("PartialName")` все работает.

update: Есть ли разница если при создании представления не ставить галочку "Создать как частичное представление" (в каких нибудь настройках это прописывается)

Возможно программно узнать является ли частичное представление строго типизированным или нет?

Comment: Посмотрите вот эти ссылки: [Load PartialView with using jquery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947606/5275890) и [Rendering Partial Views using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431105/5275890) сделайте что-то похожее. Либо добавьте чуть больше кода, представления к примеру. Либо добавьте модель в частичное представление, а в контроллере, просто через запятую добавьте ее, чтобы передать в него как тут: [Dynamically pass Model to partialview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045594/5275890)

Comment: вся разница в галке при создании представления будет в том, назначен ли `Layout` в коде представления. и зачем узнавать типизированность представления? Тут либо класс модели в представлении прописан явно, либо нет, вот и вся разница

Comment: а по сабжу вы просто модель не передаете в частичное. А когда выводите через `Partial` то у вас родительская модель используется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Не передается модель в частичное представление

Вы ее в принципе и не передаете, ибо используете сигнатуру метода

```
Controller.PartialView (String)
```

> Создает объект PartialViewResult, выполняющий визуализацию частичного
>   представления, используя заданное имя представления.

Таким образом модель данных вы не передаете вообще, и она остается `null`. В то же время вы пишите, что модель одинакова  в частичном и обычном представлении. То есть она все же должна быть. Отсюда вы и получаете закономерный `null reference exception`. По этой же причине работает `@Html.Partial("PartialName")`, когда представление пользует родительскую модель данных (*они ведь одинаковы*).

Ваш метод должен испоьзовать сигнатуру `PartialView(string, object)`

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult loadPartial(string partialName)
{
    var model  = new MyViewModel();
    model.data = ....;

    return PartialView(path, model);
}
```

по доп вопросам:

- галка "Частичное предсталвение" влияет только на установку `layout` в коде представления.
- Строгая типзированность представления только указывает конкретный класс @Model в начале представления. На выходе вы получаете либо `WebViewPage<MyViewModel>` либо `WebViewPage<dynamic>`

---

*небольшое дополнение про определение типизации (код, конечно, не проверенный, ссылка в комментариях). Вероятно, как-то так*

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult loadPartial(string partialName)
{
    var path =  //  ... + partialName;
    Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(path);
    var modelProperty = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Model");

    if (modelProperty == null || modelProperty.PropertyType != typeof(MyViewModel))          
        return PartialView(path) ;    // модель не используется

    var model  = new MyViewModel();
    model.data = ....;
    return PartialView(path, model);       
}
```

*технически это решение вероятно дает ответ на вопрос, но возможно стоит  несколько изменить логику, т.к. это не совсем нормальное поведение для приложения с первого взгляда.*

Comment: Спасибо. А возможно ли программно узнать строго типизированное представление или нет? Просто изначально не известно  стоит ли передавать в частичное представление модель или нет, а то получится что в нетипизированное представление будет передаваться модель и возникнет ошибка скорее всего

Comment: мне кажется ошибка там возникнут может лишь в том случае, когда в строго типизированное предствление вы передадите модель другого класса. Тут куда большая проблема в том, что лишний раз эту модель формировать будете, вероятно дергая БД. Как альтернативный способ - использовать некий префикс или суффикс в именовании представлений. Но, возможно, способ и есть, я, честно сказать, не знаю

Comment: @e1s вот вам кстати вариант определния типа модели представления https://stackoverflow.com/a/26683290/1216425. В вашем случае нужны центральные пару строк.

Comment: @e1s дополнил ответ